# How to Manage Bulk of transaction through web3.js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, gas, nodejs

I have following code to send a transaction:

```
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_1)
const transaction = contract.methods.submitHash(docHash);
const options  = {
    to      : transaction._parent._address,
    data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
    gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address}),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('20', 'gwei')),
};
```

- I want to be able to call web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction more than 50 times with different messages. I want to have a transaction for each message stored so that I can have tx hash.  Txhash is required so that we can easily view that the hash of a document is stored in the ethereum blockchain. The problem when I use a for loop is the nonce doesn't seem to increase.
  I get: `replacement transaction underpriced`
- Also I will be having a less gas fee for each transactions to send bulk of transaction so, does that mean if one transaction takes a long time to get mined the following transactions won't begin to be broadcasted at all? Will **batch ethereum transaction** do the trick or will I have to wait for a very long time as the transaction fee provided will be low and needs in average 3 hours for each transaction to get mined?

Comment: You can batch them in a contract's constructor, then execute them in a single transaction (of deploying the contract).

Comment: Also, you can add a `nonce` field to the `options` object, and increment it yourself.

Comment: Hey but I get the messages at different times and use a cron job to perform transactions. I want to be able to execute the function to store the hash of a document.

Comment: In your cron job, you can gather a few messages, then auto generate a contract which adds them in its constructor, then auto-compile that contract, then auto-deploy it.

Comment: I need a transaction hash for each message. So different Transaction for each message. But adding the messages in constructor won't generate tx hashes for each txns?

Comment: Yes, like I said, you can write each **function call** inside your contract constructor, then deploy the contract as a **single transaction**.

Comment: What do you need the tx hashes for?

Comment: So that a customer can check the etherscan to verify that a hash of document is stored in the ethereum blockchain. And also for timestamp of each document hash stored. WILL I GET txhash returned if I call the function through a contract constructor?

Comment: You can emit all that in an event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109816/discussion-between-subik-and-goodvibration).